# Blurry CATextLayer with scale transform

Tags: cocoa, text, core-animation, blurry, catextlayer

I'm at my wits end. I've tried what I think is everything to get rid of `CATextLayer` blurriness to no avail. Admittedly, some things help, but text is still far too blurry when zoomed in 2x and nowhere near the crispness of non-`CATextLayer` text.

Here's my situation. I've got a layer-hosted view which can contain many sublayers, including `CATextLayers` (inside a custom `CALayer` container). Now, the user can zoom the main content layer (which contains all the sublayer content) and this is done by applying a scale transform to the content layer.

Here are the things I'm currently doing. Most make a difference, though not a huge difference. If I zoom in all the way (which is 2x scale factor) I get seriously blurry text.

- Ensure integral coordinates - works and makes an appreciable difference, but still far too blurry at 2x scale
- Turn off shadows on `CATextLayer` container layers - makes a difference though not at 2x scale
- Ensure background color of text layer is fully opaque - seems to make a difference though not at 2x scale
- Set the `contentsScale` property to the window backing scale factor for all layers - seems to make a difference though not at 2x scale
- Override `-drawInContext:` of this custom `CATextLayer` subclass to smooth, anti-alias, and sub-pixel quantize the hell out of everything - fonts render much truer, but still blurry at 2x scale

Code fragment:

```
- (void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // Allow font smoothing.
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
    CGContextSetAllowsFontSmoothing(context, YES);
    CGContextSetAllowsFontSubpixelPositioning(context, YES);
    CGContextSetAllowsFontSubpixelQuantization(context, YES);

    // Set drawing attributes.
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.foregroundColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.backgroundColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

    // Font smoothing.
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(context, YES);
    CGContextSetShouldSubpixelPositionFonts(context, YES);
    CGContextSetShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts(context, YES);

    [super drawInContext:context];
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sharpest possible text, in addition to everything mentioned in the original question, the solution that had the biggest impact is to double the `contentsScale` value for text layers to twice the window backing scale factor - if you want to support crisp text at 2x zoom.

If you want to support crisp text at higher zoom values then use the max zoom factor for your application as an adjusted `contentsScale`. For example, you can do this by overriding `-setContentsScale:` for a custom `CATextLayer` subclass:

```
- (void) setContentsScale:(CGFloat)contentsScale
{
    [super setContentsScale:contentsScale * kMaxZoomFactor];
}
```

Note, be sure that changes to view backing properties (e.g., change to screen with higher resolution) are propagated to your layer-hosted hierarchy by overriding `-viewDidChangeBackingProperties` for your layer-hosted view:

```
- (void) viewDidChangeBackingProperties
{
    // Propagate self.window.backingScaleFactor change to layer hierarchy.
}
```